# Covolution of two Discrete Fourier transforms

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution

Given two finite sequences x(i) and y(i), i = 1...n. I known that the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of the pointwise product x.y is equal to convolution between two DFT of x and y:

```
DFT(x.y) = (DFT(x) * DFT(y))/n
```

Now I test in python this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([0.1, 1, 0.5])

Dftxy = np.fft.fft(x*y) # DFT(x.y)

Dftx = np.fft.fft(x)
Dfty = np.fft.fft(y)
CDftxy = np.convolve(Dftx,Dfty,'same') / 3 # (DFT(x)*DFT(y))/n
```

The result is:

```
Dftxy = [3.60+0.j, -1.65-0.4330127j, -1.65+0.4330127j]
CDftxy = [-2.10-0.40414519j, -1.65+0.4330127j, 0.40+0.j]
```

The values of Dftxy and CDftxy are different. Is there any error in my code?

Comment: Thank Mohammed Li, I tried to test in python using numpy, but the result is not correct. The code is shown in my modifed question.

Comment: Let's just avoid the caps, it's considered yelling and not very friendly. I don't get the downvotes. If y'all are so smart, show an example that works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to zero-pad your FFTs if you want your fast convolution results to produce a linear convolution result.  Otherwise, if you don't zero pad, you will get a circular convolution (end convolution results wrap around and sum with the front) from the element-wise multiplication of 2 FFTs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform it back:

```
recovered_vector = np.fft.ifft(CDftxy)
```

but yeah, periodic boundary conditions .. you will not see anything reasonable for three membered vector